# Tableau Trend line -date calculations

Tags: sql, date, tableau-api, calculation

I have dimension as date,  --(Date has discrete dates- some dates from this months , some dates from last  and so on - with data.)
more dimensions are : Team name & Team ID
other dimension is Result.
Result column has value : pass or fail  ---only two values.

below data gets refreshed everyday.

```
date      Team name Team ID Result
24/07/2008  lol      458    pass
27/01/2017  pop     1478    fail
28/02/2018  laugh     99    pass
and so on
```

---

I want to show dates on x axis, Result : Pass or Fail on trend-lines .
what would be my Y axis?

Want to show pass or fail team ID wise on trend lines!

**If its December month then team ID  which have passed /failed for 31st of December 2017 should show up. 
similarly for Jan month (team ID )  which have passed or failed should show of 31st jan 2018.
AND for Feb month it should show pass / fail for current date --- {Team count pass or fail for particular current day}**

please help with **calculated filed calculations**

Comment: any specific reason on trend lines requirement for pass or fail?  also is that your data only one record for month?

Comment: over days or months records will change to pass or fail ...there is result column and values pass or fail. Result is KI which is already calculated at database

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if Date= today() then 1
elseif dateadd('day',-
day(DATEADD('month',1,Date)),DATEADD('month',1,Date))=Date then 1
else 0
```

than set filter to 1